# Some help needed in URL rewriting

Tags: apache

I have a particular set of URLs. Something like these..

```
http://abc.com/tb/theme/images/fbIcon.gif
http://abc.com/tb/theme/css/main.css
```

This structure has been set on live machine. On my personal machine, it is not same only for tb part. On my machine it would be like.

```
http://abc.com/prod-tb/theme/images/fbIcon.gif
http://abc.com/prod-tb/theme/css/main.css
```

So I want to know how can I write a RewriteRule in .htaccess file, that will convert only        /tb/ to /prod-tb/ and rest will be same.

I tried this

```
RewriteRule   ^tb* prod-tb
```

But what happens is after tb it removed entire url. I cant figure out how this can be done. I referred to couple of references, but they were all about a specific url. What I want is related to multiple folders and files within them. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tb/(.*)$ http://abc.com/prod-tb/$1 [L]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tb/(.*)$ /prod-tb/$1 [L]
```

Hope it helps